# No reaction in net ionic equation for lithium nitrate and sodium chloride?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ions, ionic-compounds

I've heard that nothing in the following net ionic equation reacts:

$$
\ce{Li+ + NO3- + Na+ + Cl- -> \text{"nothing"}}
$$

Is this true? Could someone explain why there would be no reaction?

Comment: I assume this is meant to be in aqueous solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all these ions are in an aqueous solution, according to solubility rules nitrates are soluble, chlorides (with the exception of AgCl, PbCl₂, and Hg₂Cl₂) are soluble, and salts containing group 1 elements are soluble so they all remain as individual ions as nothing can come together to form an insoluble compound and precipitate out of the solution.

Comment: short and clear, thx!